# Assigning the Storyboard.Target on something gives me a weird error

Tags: c#, silverlight

When I write Storyboard.Target, intellisense steps in and does it's job. But when I compile it, I get an exception. But if it's no allowed, why does intellisense pull it for me to use?

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication5.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="570" d:DesignHeight="310" Width="570" Height="310">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#003399">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                <Image x:Name="imagenAnuncioDestacado" Source="DSC01969.JPG" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Grid>            

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle" MouseLeftButtonDown="myRectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown" Fill="#CCFFCC" Width="200" Height="30" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" >
            <Image x:Name="imagenLeft" Source="left.PNG" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid> 

        <Grid Grid.Column="2" >
            <Image x:Name="imagenRight" Source="right.PNG" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>

        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowPrice">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="myRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" >
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0 1,0" Value="300" KeyTime="0:0:0.8" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.10, 0.21 0.00, 1.0" Value="250" KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid>   

</UserControl>
```

Exception:

> Error 1   The property 'Target' does not exist on the type 'DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.  C:\Documents and Settings\Sergio\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SilverlightApplication5\SilverlightApplication5\MainPage.xaml 37  44  SilverlightApplication5

I want to assign myStoryboard to myRectangle. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set Storyboard.TargetName not Storyboard.Target.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Height)"
```